# Socket Connection on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsxmlparser

I want to establish socket connection between iphone and a web service that has its own IP address, service name (e.g "_abc._tcp"), and it also contains information about files stored. How can I do this? Can you please help with some sample code or links.

My goal is to develop an application that will get a video file from that server to my iphone and play it. 
At first I try to get information of the files but I don't know how to connect to that server and make the video played on my iPhone.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great library for socket programming in objc here [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

Which will help you out a lot. The examples also show how to use NSNetServices to broadcast a Bonjour service.

Comment: Which class is the most simple one, I am a beginner to iPhone? I cannot understand this mass code ^^

Comment: There are loads of examples in the repo that you can look through. This link is good to get you started [link](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket)

Comment: Of course, but I cannot vote for you^^, so I just send feedback this useful^^